# Можно ли сменить никнейм в steam с помощью steam api key?

Tags: api, steam

Возможно ли сменить имя в стиме с помощью api key
Если нет, то как можно автоматизировать смену ника, чтобы информация бралась с какого-либо сайта и никнейм сам изменялся

Answer (score 0):

Нет! Апи только выводит результат для последующей работы с ним